@SQLSELECT annotation is not picked up during execution of query
I am using hibernate @SQLSELECT annotation to filter values of some parameters(applying this annotation on paramter not on entire class), but it seems on running query that statement inside @SQLSELECT is not executed, what should I do.
I am using .findAll() method of JPARepository Class to read data, so many other procedures involving filtering using CriteriaQuery and all will not work here.
If someone have any idea regarding it, please comment
I tried @SQLSELECT, @SQLRESTRICTION(it worked in case of One-Many relationships only)
